# How can I use the same DataSource for multiple DataGridViews with a different filter applied on each?

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, datagridview, filter

I'm a beginner in C# and .NET am I am having the following problem (using .NET 4.5):

I have three DataGridViews which should display data from a xml file. Each DataGrid should filter its results, so they xml entries are spread over three DataGridViews.

I tried the following:

```cs
DataSet dataSet1 = new DataSet();
dataSet1.ReadXml('some-existing-file.xml');

DataTableCollection tables = dataSet1.Tables;
DataView view1 = new DataView(tables[0]);

BindingSource source1 = new BindingSource();
source1.DataSource = view1;
source1.Filter = "color = 'red'";
gridView1.DataSource = source1;

BindingSource source2 = new BindingSource();
source2.DataSource = view1;
source2.Filter = "color = 'white'";
gridView2.DataSource = source2;

BindingSource source3 = new BindingSource();
source3.DataSource = view1;
source3.Filter = "color = 'blue'";
gridView3.DataSource = source3;
```

But this does not work. All three GridViews use the last filter ('blue)'.

The XML looks like this (simplified):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<collection>
    <entry>
        <color>blue</color>
        <headline>Some headline</headline>
    </entry>
    [...]
</collection>
```

And is just filtering the same dataset the right way when I want to write changes back to the xml file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take three view as I think all three filters are applied on view and you get output showing the the result of last filter. You can later improve it, if it works

```
DataView view1 = new DataView(tables[0]);
DataView view2 = new DataView(tables[0]);
DataView view3 = new DataView(tables[0]);


BindingSource source1 = new BindingSource();
source1.DataSource = view1;
source1.Filter = "color = 'red'";
gridView1.DataSource = source1;

BindingSource source2 = new BindingSource();
source2.DataSource = view2;
source2.Filter = "color = 'white'";
gridView2.DataSource = source2;

BindingSource source3 = new BindingSource();
source3.DataSource = view3;
source3.Filter = "color = 'blue'";
gridView3.DataSource = source3;
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that DataView has a publicly readable collection which is modified by the filter. When you are setting your data sources, supplying view1 in that way will provide a reference of the DataView, rather than a copy. This means that all of the filters are modifying the same viewable collection in the same DataView instance (which would explain why the last filter is the filter that is working).

I would suggest creating seperate instances/copies of the DataView for each filtering case. This would remain within your scope however, as they will still be referencing the same data that has been loaded from your xml file.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for clarifying this. I wasn't aware that view1 is only a reference not a copy.

Comment: When dealing with class variables, you are always dealing with references, even when passed as parameters (unlike with primitive types which do copy themselves). If you ever wish to use multiple copies of a class instance, you must explicitly copy it; either using your own methods or by using the supplied methods in the .NET framework.

There are cases however when copying is done for you, such as when you instantiate a collection with an array or with another collection; the collection constructor performs the copying for you using the reference you provide.

Answer (score 1):

`DataView view1 = new DataView(tables[0]);` should be changed to prepare new DataView obj for each gridview as follows.

```
DataView view1 = new DataView(tables[0].Copy());
DataView view2 = new DataView(tables[0].Copy());
DataView view3 = new DataView(tables[0].Copy());
```